# Ubuntu Core 18 - nano editor permission denied for /etc/netplan/config.yaml

Tags: 18.04, permissions, snap, ubuntu-core

Using ubuntu core trying to edit netplan config in `/etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml`

This command `sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml`

Outputs
`[ Error reading /etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml: Permission denied ]`

nano was installed with `sudo snap install nano`
Is there a way to edit `/etc` configuration files with a snap store text editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ubuntu core you have to copy the netplan file to /home/user before editing, then copy it back to etc/netplan and apply. Connect nano to home interface.